# armcc or arm gcc Compiler command line option for global variable

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I wonder if there is a compiler command option to tell the compiler not to optimize global variables.

I know that declaring a variable as volatile prevent the compiler from optimizing the variable, but is it possible to use a compiler command option to turn off optimization for global variables in case of optimizing the code for speed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the effect of optimization of a global variable that you don't want?

Comment: I noticed that my application crashes always whenever a bitwise operation is used. For example, if I have this operation  (uint16_t)(msg->data.c[3]|(msg->data.c[4] << 8));  and msg variable is not declared as volatile, then my app crashes. Only with volatile keyword, then there is no crash. May be there is a compiler flag option to prevent the compiler to optimize bitwise operation as well?

Comment: My search till now reached me to a flag called --retain=option but i haven't reached the correct option till now. I am using armcc --> In this 
 docu, you can see all options allowed for optimization
 https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124194749.htm

Comment: In case of the crashing version, did you look into the generated machine code to see **_why_** it crashes? -- Did you compare this with the machine code of the non-crashing version? -- Is it possible that `msg` is `NULL` for other reasons?

Comment: by machine code, you mean the assembly version? also disassembly, that i have not looked at yet. I will compare between the optimized and non optimized version. The msg pointer is not null, actually msg->data.[0]..till [7] have values, that i can see when i print them out.